# C-Ares callback doesnt receive arg from query

Tags: c, callback, c-ares

I'm using the c-ares library to perform dns lookups on a set of domains stored in a file. Something like this.

```
char *line = NULL; 
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        if (line && line[strlen(line)-1]=='\n') line[strlen(line)-1]=0;
        printf("Sending %s\n", line);
        ares_query(channel, line, ns_c_in, ns_t_mx, callback, line);
    }
```

The last parameter to the ares_query function is of type void *arg which is just passed back to the callback function. Details here -

```
typedef void (*ares_callback)(void *arg, int status, int timeouts, unsigned char *abuf, int alen)

void ares_query(ares_channel channel, const char *name, int dnsclass, int type, ares_callback callback, void *arg)
```

The ares_query call above doesn't seem to pass "line" and I receive a NULL variable in the callback. However, when i call it with a literal like this, it seems to pass the arg.

```
ares_query(channel, line, ns_c_in, ns_t_mx, callback, "HELLO");
```

What is the difference between the two approaches? Why does the first method not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should allocate memory to the variable passed to void pointer:

```
char *line;
line = malloc(stringLength*sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, i ended up doing something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I actually allocated memory to a new variable, copied the contents of the string into that and passed it instead, it seems to work now.

```
arg = (char*) malloc(strlen(line) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(arg, line);
ares_query(channel, line, ns_c_in, ns_t_mx, callback, arg);
```